# I need to be able to execute a PowerShell script inside my C# code in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, powershell

Below is the code that I currently have to run my Powershell script in my C# program.

```
         using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                string script = "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted; Get-ExecutionPolicy"; // the second command to know the ExecutionPolicy level
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript(script);
                var someResult = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
                someResult.ToList().ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine(c.ToString()));
                //Console.ReadLine();
            }

            {
                Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                runspace.Open();
                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                Command myCommand = new Command ("C:\\automate\\dandf\\onboarding\\Yardi_Automation\\Yardi_Automation\\Onboarding_Master\\O365_Add_User.ps1");
                pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);
                pipeline.Invoke();
                runspace.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Powershell script executed..");
        }
    }
```

The script once ran will add an O365 license to any user that is put through the system. Every time I run the code it will stop at "pipeline.Invoke();) for 1 second and will move on without running the script. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Runspace Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP9jV.png)

Comment: Is there some sort of authentication step for Office365 that is needed for your O365_Add_User.ps1 to run property that you are not doing?

Comment: Check the HadErrors and Output properties of the pipeline.

Comment: Daniel, when the script runs it is supposed to prompt for a username and password. But when I run it in visual studio it does not prompt for one. It is built into the script.

Comment: djones - When I run runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(); I get a bunch of error messages stating +  Applications '($ReturnValue1).Applications' threw an exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InvalidRunspaceStateException' System.Collections.Generic.List<string> {System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InvalidRunspaceStateException}

You can see the error on the link above labeled "Runspace Error".

Comment: djones Here is the HadErrors HadErrors = true, ErrorStream = {System.Management.Automation.Internal.ObjectStream}, Error = {System.Management.Automation.Internal.ObjectReader}, Commands = Count = 1 System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline {System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline}